# Simple API call to parse JSON

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently trying to build a simple web application in Ruby on Rails connecting to the OMBD api. I am new to Ruby and coding in general. I am trying to run a FOR loop to collect all the titles from a search query. Here is my method

```
def self.findAllTitles(title)         
  allresponses = []         
  for page in 1..100 do                    
    url="http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=#{title}&page=#{page}"         
    response = HTTParty.get(url)         
    responsebody = JSON.parse(response.body) 
    allresponses.concat(responsebody)         
  end                 
  return allresponses []     
end
```

Code from my View:

```
<% @responsealltitles.each do |result| %>
<td><%= result["Title"] %></td>
<td><%= result["Year"] %></td>
```

I am getting the following error when trying to run the application:

no implicit conversion of Hash into Array

Extracted source (around line #11):
    puts responsebody = JSON.parse(response.body)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you get is not a hash. It is an array of hashes. Please try printing out responsebody[0].

```
responsebody = [{}, {}]
```

I guess your response body is as above code. Calling reponsebody[0] will take out the first element in the array(that is the response hash you need).

Comment: Here is an example of a call that would be made:

Comment: {"Search":[{"Title":"The Grand Budapest Hotel","Year":"2014","imdbID":"tt2278388"}],"totalResults":"1095","Response":"True"}

Comment: So I believe it is a hash, and there is an array nested in the hash, and then there are multple hashes in the array. Any thoughts how I would extract all the hashes from this JSON response?

Comment: Cool. So you get the above response in the variable 'responsebody', which is a hash and trying to concatenate to an array which you initialized above. Concatenation happens only between two arrays, not between an array and hash.

Comment: I understand the basics of this, but I am struggling to see how I would change my code to pull all the data from the array. Apologies for the silly question. I am really new to coding in general.

Comment: Can you please replace 'allresponses.concat(responsebody)' with 'allresponses.concat(responsebody["Search"])'. This will take the search array and append to the empty array passed initially. Finally you can see the result in views too. Please check and put in your comments

Comment: Thanks Shabini. That has worked. I was trying to use :Search instead of "Search". Now to try output this in the view. Will give you a shout if I get stuck.

Comment: Welcome. And sure, any doubts, please put in queries. :)

Comment: It appears as though my loop in my view is not working correctly. I can only assume I am not outputing the correct format.

Comment: <tr>
<% @responsealltitles.each do |result| %>
<td><%= result["Title"] %></td>
<td><%= result["Year"] %></td>
<td><%= result["Rated"] %></td>
<td><%= result["Awards"] %></td>

Comment: This is the error I am getting: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: Can you please display what does @responsealltitles have?

Comment: {"Search"=>[{"Title"=>"The Grand Budapest Hotel", "Year"=>"2014", "imdbID"=>"tt2278388", "Type"=>"movie", "Poster"=>"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzM5NjUxOTEyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjEyMDM0MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg"}, {"Title"=>"Hotel Rwanda", "Year"=>"2004", "imdbID"=>"tt0395169", "Type"=>"movie", "Poster"=>"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI2MzQyNTc1M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjExNjc3._V1_SX300.jpg"}], "totalResults"=>"1095", "Response"=>"True"}

Comment: I have changed my view to use the following code: <% @responsealltitles.each do |result| %>
<td><%= result[0]["Title"] %></td>
<td><%= result[0]["Year"] %></td>
<td><%= result[0]["imdbID"] %></td>

Comment: Change the code as this, <%@responsealltitles["Search"].each do |result| %> <td><%= result["Title"] %></td> <td><%= result["Year"] %></td> <td><%= result["imdbID"] %></td><%end%>

Comment: The change has not created any issues, but its obviously not populating the way I would like. I can only gather I am calling data from this hash incorrectly

Comment: Brilliant. That worked. I thought I had tested that before. Clearly I did not.